# Android Release APK Getting Error NoSuchFieldError

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk, android-proguard

Please help,

this is my first time to generate release APK using android studio, after try for a few days, I can signing my project but when I install the apk I always get this **error**..

```
7290-7290/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.enma.app, PID: 7290
            java.lang.NoSuchFieldError
                at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.decodeValue(AnnotationAccess.java:688)
                at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:663)
                at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:641)
                at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getDeclaredAnnotation(AnnotationAccess.java:171)
                at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getAnnotation(AnnotationAccess.java:72)
                at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:359)
                at com.c.a.c.f.al.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                at com.c.a.c.f.al.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.c.a.c.z.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                at com.zopim.android.sdk.data.Parser.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at com.zopim.android.sdk.data.Path.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at com.zopim.android.sdk.data.ConnectionPath.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at com.zopim.android.sdk.data.ConnectionPath.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                at com.zopim.android.sdk.data.PathDataSource.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at com.zopim.android.sdk.api.ZopimChat.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                at com.enma.app.MyApp.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1018)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4914)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1526)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5683)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
            Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field PUBLIC_ONLY in class Lcom/c/a/a/g; (declaration of 'com.c.a.a.g' appears in /data/app/com.enma.app-1/base.apk)
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
                at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.decodeValue(AnnotationAccess.java:685)
                at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:663) 
                at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:641) 
                at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getDeclaredAnnotation(AnnotationAccess.java:171) 
                at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getAnnotation(AnnotationAccess.java:72) 
                at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:359) 
                at com.c.a.c.f.al.<clinit>(Unknown Source) 
                at com.c.a.c.f.al.a(Unknown Source) 
                at com.c.a.c.z.<clinit>(Unknown Source) 
                at com.zopim.android.sdk.data.Parser.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                at com.zopim.android.sdk.data.Path.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                at com.zopim.android.sdk.data.ConnectionPath.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                at com.zopim.android.sdk.data.ConnectionPath.<clinit>(Unknown Source) 
                at com.zopim.android.sdk.data.PathDataSource.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                at com.zopim.android.sdk.api.ZopimChat.<clinit>(Unknown Source) 
                at com.enma.app.MyApp.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1018) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4914) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1526) 
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5683) 
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

this is my **gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.enma.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.HPAY
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile files('libs/disklrucache-2.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.zopim.android:sdk:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank You

---

Thanks for the responds this is my proguard, for now my apps can work properly, but why the obfuscating not work for some source.

[image]

**Proguard**

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
#-dontoptimize
#-dontpreverify

# If you want to enable optimization, you should include the
# following:
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification
#
# Note that you cannot just include these flags in your own
# configuration file; if you are including this file, optimization
# will be turned off. You'll need to either edit this file, or
# duplicate the contents of this file and remove the include of this
# file from your project's proguard.config path property.
-dontwarn **

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment

-keep class com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keep interface com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.** {*;}
-keep class com.zopim.android.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.http.** {*;}

-ignorewarnings

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}


-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Comment: post pro-guard file.

Comment: Have you created an Application class to extend MultidexApplication ?

Comment: **compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'** to  **compileSdkVersion "23"**

Comment: @brahmyadigopula i think so

Comment: You need to translate the obfuscated class name `com.c.a.a.g` using `mapping.txt` to the original one. Then adapt the proguard config accordingly. Or you simply disable the obfucation in ProGuard until your app works in your test environment.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is clearly in the one of the annotations of the class `com.c.a.c.f.al`. It seems to be trying to access a field called `PUBLIC_ONLY` that appears in class `com.c.a.a.g`.

To figure out what `com.c.a.c.f.al` and `com.c.a.a.g` are, just look for the `mappings.txt` file that ProGuard generates (usually appears in *build/outputs/mapping/.../mapping.txt*) and search for the lines that show what these classes were named before being obfuscated. Mappings would have entries like this:

```
com.yourapp.class1 -> com.c.a.c.f.al
```

Once you find the class that contains `PUBLIC_ONLY`, make sure you exclude it from being obfuscated by adding a line similar to this to your ProGuard configuration file:

```
-keep class com.yourapp.class1 { *; }
```

If this works, you should try to target only the `PUBLIC_ONLY` field by replacing `*;` by something like `*** PUBLIC_ONLY;`